# Are SATA 1, 2 and 3 cables interchangeable?

Tags: sata, cable

I've got an older SATA drive (not sure if it's SATA 1 or 2). Same size plug as my new SATA 3 M/B.

Are the cables interchangeable?
Any decrease in performance from using a "lower" cable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Normally nothing has changed between the cables between SATA I,II and III. From the official SATA-IO document:

> The same cables and connectors used for current SATA implementations
>   can be used to connect SATA 6Gb/s devices. SATA-IO recommends
>   utilizing quality components to ensure data integrity and robust
>   operation at the fast 6Gb/s transfer rate. Cables already at the
>   threshold of 3Gb/s operating margins may experience lower performance
>   than expected at 6Gb/s due to an increased number of resends.

You can have a look at some benchmarks [here](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/SATA-cables-Is-there-a-difference-97/).

Answer (score 7):

Yep. They're interchangeable. All SATA is [backward (and forward) compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Backward_and_forward_compatibility).